# How to find the x value that makes the vertices create a right triangle?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, triangles

Essentially, there are 3 points $A=(10, −2, −10)$, $B=(20, −6, 0)$, and $C=(x, −2, −9)$ and I'm trying to find what value of $x$ makes ABC a right triangle. The issue is I don't really know how to attack the problem. I tried using dot product, but that didn't work, then I tried finding the distance between the vectors to see if something would work, but that didn't help either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The dot product works for me. Make sure that you use the sides: $AB=B-A=(10,-4,10)$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned in the comment, the things that are perpendicular are the sided of the triangle:
$$\begin{align}AB&=&B-A&=&(20,-6,0)-(10,-2,-10)&=&(10,-4,10)\\
AC&=&C-A&=&(x,-2,-9)-(10,-2,-10)&=&(x-10,0,1)\\
BC&=&C-B&=&(x,-2,-9)-(20,-6,0)&=&(x-20,4,-9)\end{align}$$
Now we have several cases:

- $\angle A=90^\circ$ means $AB\cdot AC=0$ or $10x-100+10=0$, or $x=9$
- $\angle B=90^\circ$ means $AB\cdot BC=0$ or $10x-200-16-90=0$ or $x=30.6$
- $\angle C=90^\circ$. $AC\cdot BC=0$ or $x^2-30x+200-9=0$. If I got this right, you have two solutions, $x_1\approx 20.83$ and $x_2\approx9.17$

**Geometrical interpretation:**

Let's start with segment $AB$ as above, and write the equation of the $C$ line as $$C=x(1,0,0)+(0,-2,-9)$$
It's easy to see that $C$ moves along a line that is not perpendicular to $AB$. Then take the line $AB$. Draw the plane perpendicular to $AB$ that passes through $A$. When the line of $C$ intersects this plane you get $AC\perp AB$. Similarly, if you use the plane perpendicular to $AB$ that contains $B$, any line in that plane is perpendicular to $AB$, in particular $BC$. For the last part, if your angle $C$ is $90^\circ$, it means that $A,B,C$ lie on a circle with diameter $AB$. So you draw a sphere through the middle of $AB$, with diameter $|AB|$. Then the line describing $C$ can intersect the sphere in two points (as found above), it can be tangent (the discriminant would have to be zero), or it can completely miss the sphere (discriminant is negative).